# in unix, is it better to sort multiple small files, or one big file?

Tags: unix, sorting

So I have multiple files that I am working on and they need to be combined and sorted. Would it be more efficient to sort each file first and use the sort -m option when combining the files, or to combine them first and then sort.

Or is it the same? My understanding is that unix uses merge sort so in essence, would the one big file be separated, sorted, and recombined anyway? So it shouldn't make a difference?

Comment: Only one way to know for sure... try it & profile it.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the files together.

```
sort file1 file2 file3 file4
```

Unless you have a lot of time to investigate, the sort command will do a better job than you in breaking the files into appropriately-sized chunks, sort them independently and recombine them.