# Minimize disk usage while doing unix sort

Tags: unix, sorting

I have a lot of files, say 1000 files, each with 4mb. Totally there are 4gb. I would like to sort them by using unix sort, here is my command:

```
sort -t ',' -k 1,1 -k 5,7 -k 22,22 -k 2,2r INPUT_UNSORTED_${current_time}.DAT -o INPUT_SORTED_${current_time}.DAT
```

where INPUT_UNSORTED is a big file created by appending the 1000 files. So there is another 4gb. INPUT_SORTED is another 4gb too.

And I discovered unix sort used a temp folder to sort the files, and the temp files may reach to 4gb too.

How can I reduce disk usage without losing performance?

Comment: Maybe you should not concat your 1000 files, but give them to "sort" separately: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581215/in-unix-is-it-better-to-sort-multiple-small-files-or-one-big-file

Answer (score 2):

Is your goal to get a single big sorted output file?  Take a look at sort's `--merge` option.  You can sort the small input files individually, and then merge them all into the large sorted output.  If you delete each unsorted input file immediately after producing its sorted counterpart, you won't use more than 4MB of space on intermediate results.

Comment: My final goal is to split the big output into smaller files in 4mb. And I don't want to delete the input files immediately, because error may happens and my input files could be lost.

Comment: You can check the exit status of `sort` to see whether it succeeded before deleting the input file, so you won't lose data if it fails.  And I assume that you're combining all the files together because you want to sort them together, so that if the file `input99` contains "aardvark", it'll go in `output1`, not the beginning of `output99`.  Otherwise you could just sort each 4MB file individually.